# Kubernetes Webhook - Multiple hubs defined for group-kind

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk, kubebuilder

Trying to deploy my webhook using operator-sdk I got this error in the logs:

```
conversion check failed {"object": {"metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null},"spec":{},"status":{}}, "error": "multiple(2) hubs defined for group-kind '' "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to kubebuilder [documentation](https://book.kubebuilder.io/multiversion-tutorial/conversion-concepts.html) there must be only one hub Conversion and as many Spokes as versions your CRD has.

[image]

In my case there were 2 Hubs methods, so I just delete one of them.